# How do I receive email in Excel

Tags: excel, email

how can I ***read*** email from my GMail account using Excel?

Here is what I have considered:

1. Using the CDO object. 
   Problem: I don't think that this object *can* receive emails.
2. Using web scraping with an IE or xmlHTTP object. This is one way to go, and I already have experience and VBA code to do much of the work but it's not simple.
3. Interfacing with Microsoft Outlook. Problem: Why lock myself in to a more expensive product that Microsoft will want me to pay for when upgrading?
4. Running an iMacros to scape the data. I have not explored this way properly (because I am hoping to stick to Excel) although it may be the simplest.

Any ideas? What is the simplest reliable way?
Thanks!

P.S. Google search shows many many pages with instructions to *send* emails using Excel. That's too easy :) . I am trying to *retrieve/read* emails using Excel.

Comment: Related (unanswered) question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16828411/2258

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the overall goal here is, but I would suggest you are approaching it wrong.

If the goal is to put a list of emails into an Excel file, I would suggest you write the email code in Java, C#, VB, etc. and then generate an Excel file from that.

It's far easier to generate Excel files after getting email information than it is to get email information from VBA.

Comment: I have a program written in Excel that places stock market orders. I would like to extend this program to automatically place the orders when receiving an EMail with new stock picks. The EMail generally comes in at 8:00am on Monday morning and needs to be sent before the market opens at 9:30am. Writing the whole thing in Java is a lot of work.

Comment: Oh ok. Yeah I would still recommend moving the application to something other than Excel. You can probably find a way to check email from Excel, but that is just putting a bandaid on the application. You'll likely want to keep adding features and Excel is going to prove tough to work with.

Comment: ryan, you're probably right. Perhaps one day I will take your advice and do it the right way :). Meanwhile I have called a iMacro to save the email to a file and then read that mail in Excel.